# Anomaly detection with strong prior assumptions about data generating process

Tags: regression, anomaly-detection, finite-mixture-model

I have data that can be described using the model

$$
y \sim \mathcal{N}\big(f(x; \Theta), \, \sigma^2)
$$

where $f$ is some function with *known* functional form, but unknown parameters. I also can make an educated guesses about the parameters to come up with priors or bounds for them. The problem is that the sample is contaminated with an additional source of noise with unknown distribution $g$, so the observed data can be considered as a mixture

$$
\pi \, \mathcal{N}\big(f(x; \Theta), \,\sigma^2\big) + (1 - \pi) \,g
$$

where $\pi > 1-\pi$ is a mixing proportion (also unknown). I would like to (a) filter out the outliers and (b) estimate the $\Theta$, $\sigma^2$ parameters. I could treat this as a mixture model, but I don't know and don't care about $g$. How could I efficiently exploit the prior knowledge to solve it? I assumed that it could be trivially solved with something like the E-M algorithm or RANSAC, but I didn't find them to give satisfactory results.

Data example:

```r
set.seed(42)

# unknowns
Theta <- c(1, 3)
sigma <- 2
n1 <- 500
n2 <- 450

# known functional form
f <- \(x) Theta[1] + Theta[2] * x^2

# unknown true data subgroups
x1 <- rnorm(n1)
y1 <- rnorm(n1, f(x1), sigma)
x2 <- rnorm(n2)
y2 <- abs(rnorm(n2, sd=10))

# observed data
x <- c(x1, x2)
y <- c(y1, y2)
```

Comment: The problem as you describe it is Ill-defined. Suppose for example $g$ has a similar distribution to $y$ but with different parameters. Then there is no way you can tell which of those two sets of parameters is the true one.

Comment: It's unclear how your code (which has at least one typo, btw) is intended to match your description.  It would be helpful for $\pi,$ $g,$ $\Theta,$ and $\varepsilon$ to appear explicitly in the code, or at least for the comments to be more descriptive than they are.

Comment: @whuber I matched the code with notation, but not sure what you mean by the typo.

Comment: `f <- \(x) Theta[1] + Theta[2] * x^2` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @whuber what is incorrect?

Comment: My version of `R` complains about the syntax and I do not recognize what `\(` might mean: it's not part of the base `R` language.  My guess is that something got corrupted, ranging from a few characters to a few lines, when you pasted that expression.

Comment: @whuber; that shorthand notation was implemented in [R 4.1.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html). (S)Could just use `f <- function(x) Theta[1] + Theta[2] *x^2`

Comment: This illustrates the dangers of relying on code to convey an idea!

Comment: Can you provide plots of some example data? Both normal, anomalous and normal polluted with anomalies?

Comment: @JonNorby this is a general question, not about a particular dataset, but you can consider the code example.